# How to pass form data (not related to Entity Class) in editorjs to symfony controller (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, editorjs

Here is the form connected to database

```
class JsonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('author')
            ->add('jsondata')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => JsonBlog::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and there is HTML

```
<div>
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.author) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.author, {'attr': {'class':'form-control'}})}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.jsondata) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.jsondata, {'attr': {'class':'form-control', 'id':'body'}})}}
            </div>
            <div id="editor"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info mt">Submit</button>
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
```

I added `<div id="editor"></div>` that is not initialized in Entity Class and database.

I want to pass the value of `<div id="editor"></div>` to the Controller

```
function postData() {
    editor.save().then((outputData) => {
        console.log(outputData);
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = outputData;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Failed: ', error)
    });
    
}
```

I have tried this using JS function but it does not work.

Comment: The content of a div will not be send in a post request. Maybe use javascript to fill the value of a hidden input when submitting the form ? or something similar

Comment: Yes I have tried this but it seems does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Symfony Form: unmapped field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#unmapped-fields). As you can't pass a div element in form, you'll transform it to an input which will not be mapped to your entity. Then you can retrieve it value in your Controller.